# sbt: Add multiple resolvers

Tags: scala, sbt

I tried to add two resolvers:

```
resolvers ++= Seq(
  Resolver.DefaultMavenRepositoryRoot,
  //Resolver.sonatypeRepo("releases"),
  Resolver.typesafeRepo("releases")
)
```

However I keep getting:

> ...build.sbt:9: error: No implicit for
>   Append.Values[Seq[sbt.Resolver], Seq[java.io.Serializable]] found,
>   so Seq[java.io.Serializable] cannot be appended to Seq[sbt.Resolver]
>   resolvers ++= Seq(
>             ^ [error] Type error in expression Invalid response. Invalid response.
>
> Invalid response.

1. What are the default resolvers in the `resolvers`?
2. What is wrong? How to add multiple resolvers ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you are adding multiple resolvers is correct. The problem is with `DefaultMavenRepositoryRoot`: it's not a `Resolver`, it's just a string, and you need to provide a sequence of `Resolver`s.

That being said, you don't need to explicitly add this resolver because it's included by [default](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Resolvers.html#Predefined).

But if for some reason you do want to add it explicitly, you should use `DefaultMavenRepository`. It uses the same url in `DefaultMavenRepositoryRoot`. So you would be writing this:

```
resolvers ++= Seq(
  DefaultMavenRepository,
  //Resolver.sonatypeRepo("releases"),
  Resolver.typesafeRepo("releases")
)
```